# What does 電波調査斑 mean?

Tags: words

I was reading the Japanese wikipedia article on Pablo Escobar and came across the word 電波調査斑. What does it mean exactly? And how do you pronounce it? I take it 電波 means electronic wave, and  調査 search. But what about 斑? How does this fit in, and what is the resulting word?

The whole sentence from which this word was taken reads.

その後政府はエスコバルの一部の家族の身柄を確保し、さらに1993年12月2日、コロンビア国家警察直下のコロンビア治安部隊の電波調査斑が、メデジンの中産階級住宅街の隠れ家から息子と携帯電話で通話するエスコバルの居場所を突き止め、治安部隊の特捜チームが突入して屋根の上に逃れたエスコバルに一斉射撃を加えて殺害した.

Comment: Supposed to be 班? They share the same onyomi and look similar enough that you might not even notice the wrong one was used at a glance. Unless it's some irregular usage I don't know about.

Comment: Yes; it does look like a typo. I copy-pasted the text from wikipedia. If it's meant to be 班, the word makes much more sense.

Comment: Should be a typo. This article should be revised.

Comment: @Leebo I'm almost certain your answer is the correct one. You don't need to leave it as a comment. 調査班 shows up in dictionary and Google searches; 調査斑 doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

電波調査 is pronounced as でんぱちょうさ.

Now, an original article also provides 電波調査斑. It is not impossible to mistake　as 斑 as 班. As Seesawscene already provided, 班 may imply a team. I might add a squad for 班 in this case since it is a police team for a specific purpose.

電波 should be a radio wave. If this is correct https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23275/in-electromagnetic-radiation-how-do-electrons-actually-move , radio-wave does not contain an electron. An electron is in the antenna which produces radiation.

So, 電波調査 should be radio wave search/detection in this case.

By the way, Colombia is a beautiful place. If you like a painting, check a painter Botero. A unique style.